# Is there any parallelism issue in "I am travelling to India and shall be on leave for 2 weeks"?

Tags: parallelism

> I am travelling to India and shall be on leave for 2 weeks.

Like is the sentence correct?

travelling to -- is present continuous

shall be -- is future

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence is correct. It is "parallel" in the sense that "I" applies to both parts of the sentence and both verbs. The verbs can be of different tenses and still be correct.

The sentence you have constructed says,

> I am travelling to India.

and

> I shall be on leave for 2 weeks.

Since the same subject ("I") applies to both sentences, it's appropriate to combine them as you have.

Answer (score 0):

**and** joins two independent clauses, and their tenses can  be different.

> I am traveling into the jungle and I had to be inoculated against fever.